# PDO insert a differnet int value

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm inserting on a database with PDO but the inserted integer value is different than the expected

```
  $insert = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios(id,username,token)
        VALUES (:id,:username,:token)");
        echo $inst->getUser_Id();//here shows the correct value
      $insert->bindparam(':id',$inst->getUser_Id(),PDO::PARAM_INT);
      $insert->bindparam(':username',$inst->getUsername());
      $insert->bindparam(':token',$inst->getToken());
      $insert->execute();
      echo $inst->getUser_Id();//here shows the correct value too
```

When I check the inserted data ,the field id is different than `echo $inst->getUser_Id()`

Comment: Different how? Pls provide more details around the error! The id field is not auto I crement by any chance?

Comment: Maybe because every time you call $inst->getUser_Id() your code increment previous value?

Comment: `$inst->getUser_Id()` is  3659412867 and  2147483647 is inserted

Comment: the value is not incremented,the same value before the execute

Comment: Overflow is the keyword, then. Your id field cannot accomodate the high value

Comment: This is what I thought but id field is int(20),and still I have the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the id field is declared as signed integer, which has a [maximum value](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html) of 2147483647. Since you try to insert a bigger value than the max and apparently the strict sql mode is turned off, mysql rounds the data down to the maximum. In the `int(20)` declaration the 20 [does not influence the maximum value the field can hold](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-attributes.html). Change the datatype to bigint or unsigned int and you will be fine.

Comment: In this case pls mark the above answer as accepted to let other viewrs know that the question is solved.